# Criando seu próprio Provider Mixer e Django

Tags: django, fixtures, factory

Eu vi que no mixer existem vários providers prontos

http://fake-factory.readthedocs.org/en/latest/providers.html

http://fake-factory.readthedocs.org/en/master/locales/pt_BR.html

mas não existe um provider para 'products'. Eu queria criar um provider para 'products', dai eu vi em How to create a Provider

http://fake-factory.readthedocs.org/en/master/index.html#how-to-create-a-provider

que dá pra criar um, e para isso precisa mexer em fake-factory

[https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/faker/providers/person/pt_BR/**init**.py](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/faker/providers/person/pt_BR/__init__.py)

usando o faker

[https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/faker/providers/**init**.py#L93](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/faker/providers/__init__.py#L93)

Pergunto: Como eu faço para criar um novo provider com os meus próprios 'products'?

Comment: Ora,você mesmo respondeu sua pergunta. Os links acima possui toda informação necessária para cumprir o propósito.

Comment: Sim, mas eu não consegui, ou melhor, não sei como montar tudo isso.